# c++ even more generalized operator templating

Tags: c++, templates, operators

So I just learned (thanks guys) about decltype. I now can write really nice vector templates that actually outperform valarrays(!):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
vector<decltype(T()*U())> operator*(const vector<T>& A, const vector<U>& B){
  vector<decltype(T()*U())> C = vector<decltype(T()*U())>(A.size());
  typename vector<T>::const_iterator a = A.begin();
  typename vector<U>::const_iterator b = B.begin();
  typename vector<decltype(T()*U())>::iterator c = C.begin();
  while (a!=A.end()){
    *c = (*a) + (*b);
    a++; b++; c++;
  }
  return C;
}
```

Is it possible to make this kind of templating even more "meta", in the sense that we allow the operator ("*") itself to be a template parameter? I.e. have one single template definition that works for *, +, %, etc, where the appropriate operator op is used in *c = (*a) op (*b)?

I'm betting it is not, but it would be nice!

Comment: That's essentially a binary version of `accumulate`, though `accumulate` itself can already be used for something similar, though not quite as symmetric. Real power would probably come from lazy-evaluation wrappers, though.

Comment: ... couple of nitpicks: you probably want to use default construction for `C` and `reserve` to ensure that it will not need to grow, then use `push_back` (rather than creating the array with the size --awkwardly with the `vector<x> c = vector<x>( a.size() )`-- and rewriting the elements). Use typedefs! they help readability, a single `typedef decltype( A.front()*B.front() ) result_type` will make the code much more readable. Avoid adding unneeded requirements to generic code (the current implementation uses `T()`, `U()`, and `result_type()` imposing the existence of a default constructor)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I find that using push_back is significantly slower than the full declare/rewrite version, up to 50% slower in my test case.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I'll have to check out lazy evaluation wrappers, I don't know anything about them.

Comment: @andyInCambridge: What is the setup in which you have performed the testing? Did you *reserve* the space in advance? Note that the `reserve()` call will make a huge difference as it will ensure that a single memory allocation takes place (assuming that you reserved to the appropriate size), and in that case, it should be faster than your approach. If it is not, I would be interested in knowing what compiler, platform and test you are running...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: reserve() was the key (I hand't been using it). reserve() followed by push_back() is about 10% faster than the allocate/rewrite. Thanks!

Comment: @andyInCambridge: If you are curious about the reasons, without the `reserve()` call, the vector will grow as needed (with whatever the strategy in your STL implementation is) and that will trigger reallocations and copying of data to the new location, which is what makes it much slower. By telling it the expected size, the implementation can perform a single allocation and then just add the elements as needed. As to why that is faster than the `resize()` (or construction with a size), the reason is that `resize()` will value initialize new elements so you are actually writing twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you expected, this answer is "no." :)

However, you can use the preprocessor to generate such functions:

```
#define OPERATOR_BLOB(optype) \
    vector<…> operator optype (…) { … }

OPERATOR_BLOB(*)
OPERATOR_BLOB(+)
…
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::declval<T&&>()` instead of just `T()`, it might not have a default constructor (since std::vector does not require a default constructor, only a copy constructor). Also, be **very sure** about type & reference & rvalue reference correctness and forwarding, classes may implement things differently for values, references, const references, rvalue references. Test it with several classes.

Also, mind you that the return type extraction might not work for compound assignment operators in GCC due to an unimplemented feature.

And yes, I solved it with parameterized macros in my pointer wrapper class: http://frigocoder.dyndns.org/code/Frigo/Lang/ref

For example

```
#define PROXY_BINARY_OPERATOR(_) \
    template <class Arg> \
    decltype(std::declval<T&&>() _ std::declval<Arg&&>()) operator _ (Arg&& arg) \
    { \
        return std::forward<T>(get()) _ std::forward<Arg>(arg); \
    } \
    template <class Arg> \
    decltype(std::declval<const T&&>() _ std::declval<Arg&&>()) operator _ (Arg&& arg) const \
    { \
        return std::forward<T>(get()) _ std::forward<Arg>(arg); \
    }
```